# ASP.NET MVC 5 & Entity Framework many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Task` model. I want to assign tasks to users when I am creating a new task. Because of that I created `UserViewModel` and `CheckBoxView` model. But now I can just assign tasks to users when I am editing a user table. I know I have to change `UserController`'s `Create` action but I do not know how.

Here is my code:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserToTask> UserToTasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserToTask> UserToTasks { get; set; }
}

public class UserToTask
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
}

public class CheckBoxViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public List<CheckBoxViewModel> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

User Controller:

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private MyModel db = new MyModel();

    // GET: Users
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Users.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Users/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Users/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Surname")] User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(user);
    }

    // GET: Users/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        User user = db.Users.Find(id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        var result = from a in db.Tasks
            select new
            {
                a.Id,
                a.Title,
                Checked = (from ab in db.UserToTasks
                    where (ab.UserId == id) & (ab.TaskId == a.Id)
                    select ab).Any()
            };

        var MyViewModel = new UserViewModel();
        MyViewModel.UserId = id.Value;
        MyViewModel.Name = user.Name;
        MyViewModel.Surname = user.Surname;

        var MyCheckBoxList = new List<CheckBoxViewModel>();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            MyCheckBoxList.Add(new CheckBoxViewModel{Id = item.Id, Name = item.Title, Checked = item.Checked});
        }

        MyViewModel.Tasks = MyCheckBoxList;

        return View(MyViewModel);
    }

    // POST: Users/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var MyUser = db.Users.Find(user.UserId);
            MyUser.Name = user.Name;
            MyUser.Surname = user.Surname;

            foreach (var item in db.UserToTasks)
            {
                if (item.UserId == user.UserId)
                {
                    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in user.Tasks)
            {
                if (item.Checked)
                {
                    db.UserToTasks.Add(new UserToTask() {UserId = user.UserId, TaskId = item.Id});
                }
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(user);
    }   
}
```

Edit view:

```
@model ItalianCoach.Models.UserViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>User</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tasks, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tasks.Count(); i++)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Tasks[i].Checked)
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Tasks[i].Name)<br/>

                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Tasks[i].Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Tasks[i].Id)
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: as i mentioned i want to see all tasks when i creating a User and assign a tasks to this user. At the moment i can just create User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the `UserToTask` class. The relationships between them should be with the object classes themselves.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

You add in the TaskId as  foreign key in the User class. Each User will have a collection of Tasks (which may or may not be empty - so be careful with your constructors).

To find all the Users for a particular Task - you use a database query on Users -> where TaskId == Task.Id.

You'll need to sort out the xaml, controllers, etc, to fit the new model.

Comment: What you are describing is many-to-many model with implicit link table. But it's just one of the possible many-to-many models supported by EF - the one used by OP is the other. Since both have pros and cons, I wouldn't say this is always preferable over the other. And speaking about portability, EF Core currently supports only the model with explicit entity. So what you are suggesting is not strongly necessary. Also looks like does not address the OP issue with `Create` controller action.